# Changes to attribute in a class be activated in another class

Tags: python, inheritance, attributes

```
class Main:
    def __init__(self):
        self.number = 10

class Sub1(Main):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def addnum(self):
        self.number += 1
        print(self.number)

class Sub2(Main):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    def func(self):
        print(self.number)

sub2 = Sub2()
sub1 = Sub1()

sub1.addnum()
sub2.func()
```

In class Main, attribute number=10 is created
In class Sub1, function addnum increases number by 1
In class Sub2, function func prints the number, it prints 10, how do I make it print 11?
So how can changes to an attribute in a class be activated in another class?

Comment: ... you are using *two different instances*.

Comment: Just initialize `number` as class variable. Read: [Class and Instance Variables](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables).

Answer (score 0):

So you want `number` to be shared across `Main`, `Sub1`, and `Sub2`, so that if an instance of Sub1 modifies `number` instances of `Main` and `Sub2` can access that new number. You really don't want to do this, if you need to share variables across classes you're better off using a container that all those classes can access. For example:

```
class Container:
    number = 10

class Main:
    def __init__(self):
        self.container = Container()

    def set_number(self, new_num):
        self.container.number = new_num

class New:
    def __init__(self, main):
        self.container = main.container

    def addone(self):
        self.container.number += 1


main = Main()
new = New(main)
new.addone()

print(main.container.number) # 11

main.set_number(1000)

print(new.container.number) # 1000
```

This is just a much cleaner and easier approach.

Comment: Can you also do that with inheritance?

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean